# Get length of the Xml provided

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying load the XML

```
<Node>
<Subnode a = "1" b = "2" />
<Subnode a = "4" b = "5" />
</Node>



xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async="false";
xmlDoc.loadXML("c:\\test.xml"); 

var length = xmlDoc.childNodes.length
```

but length is Zero which is incorrect

Comment: Please use the button with {} to format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see this line is incorrect.

```
xmlDoc.loadXML("c:\\test.xml");
```

It should be

```
xmlDoc.load("c:\\test.xml");
```

See API document for the difference between [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [loadXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also it's useful to check for errors, using the [parseError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756041%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property, after calling any of the load methods. Something along these lines:

```
if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
// Handle error
}
```

In addition, as indicated in the comments, the [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761398%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property should be `false` not "false".

Comment: Hi garett,Can you please also help out in getting values for a and b

Comment: i had the answer for above question Many thank for the help xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].getAttribute("a")

Answer (score 1):

The Subnodes are children of the documentElement; try

```
xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes.length
```

The method to load a file is .load (not .loadXML).